# mfabrik web and mobile

Tags: mobile, web, plone

Where can I download the product "Web and Mobile" by mfabrik? I checked their site and didn't find a download link, even in the installation instructions page.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Helio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere like there : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mfabrik.webandmobile/

Anything you ever wanted is on PyPi.

Comment: Salut Jihsaisse! Thx for the answer. Regards, Helio

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to install the product "Web and Mobile", you can use the [installation process](http://webandmobile.mfabrik.com/docs/web-and-mobile/user-manual/installation) available on the mfabrix website. The provided buildout will download and install mfabrik.webandmobile and all his dependencies for you.